# How can I get the date of creation of my azure site

Tags: azure, date, azure-web-app-service, creation

I have a site on Azure but I am not able to see in the azure portal the date of creation and activation of my site. I need this for legal purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You may review your [Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit)- Through this, you can determine:
•   what operations were taken on the resources in your subscription
•   who initiated the operation (although operations initiated by a backend service do not return a user as the caller)
•   when the operation occurred (in your case WebApps)
•   the status of the operation
•   the values of other properties that might help you research the operation

The activity log contains all write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE) performed on your resources. It does not include read operations (GET). You can use the audit logs to find an error when troubleshooting or to monitor how a user in your organization modified a resource.

Note: Activity logs are retained for 90 days. You can query for any range of dates, as long as the starting date is not more than 90 days in the past.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need the creation date of your Azure WebAPP.

If you use **Get-AzureRmWebApp** it will return last modified, so it will not help.

What you can do is get the time-stamp (for each deployment operation), by using the Command below.

**Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name <"ResourceGroup name">| Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment**

The deployment time should be the same as creation time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great way to do this either, but similar to Clavin's answer, you can use the Azure CLI, e.g.:

```
az deployment group list  -g <your group here> --query "[?starts_with(name, 'website_deployment_')]"
```

That will list all the web app deployments - the name of the app is inside the properties.parameters under a key e.g. `appService_<name>_name` - not sure why MS made this so awfully complicated.